# sort items in table by actionlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have sorted items from [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Here's my controller:

```
ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "fname" : "";
            ViewBag.lastNameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "lastName" : "";
            ViewBag.idNumberSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "idNumber" : "";
 var persons = from s in db.PRT_PARTNERS
                          select s;
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "fname_desc":
                    persons = persons.OrderBy(s => s.FIRST_NAME);
                    break;
                case "lastName_desc":
                    persons = persons.OrderBy(s => s.LAST_NAME);
                    break;
                case "idNumber_desc":
                    persons = persons.OrderBy(s => s.PERSONAL_NUMBER);
                    break;
default:
                    persons = persons.OrderBy(s => s.FIRST_NAME);
                    break;
            }
```

And here's view:

```
 <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("სახელი", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("გვარი", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.lastNameSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("პირადი ნომერი", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.idNumberSortParm })
        </th>
```

but here's one problem. If I'll click to lastName it orders by lastname but than if I'll click to personalNumber it sorts with ***FIRSTNAME*** instead of *personalnumber*. And after that if I'll click in personalNumber it will sort by it. How can I improve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is bad.
Problem is in this code:

```
ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "fname" : "";
ViewBag.lastNameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "lastName" : "";
ViewBag.idNumberSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "idNumber" : "";
```

`HttpGet` method of your controller starts with `sortOrder == null` (I presume) and all your `ViewBag` items get some value `"fname", "lastName"` or `"idNumber"`. After that `switch` block go to `default` case because `sortOrder == null`.

But when you get an answer from view with `sortOrder` with some value, your `ViewBag` items go to null, because of `sortOrder != null`:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "idNumber" : ""; 
\\if sortOrder is not null or empty it will be empty anyway.
```

After that `switch` block goes ok ONE time but your view will return `sortOrder==null` because all your `ViewBag.Items == null` and `swith` block will go to `default` case.

TLDR
You will get `default switch` case each second time.

To solve your problem just do this:

```
ViewBag.NameSortParm = "fname";
ViewBag.lastNameSortParm = "lastName";
ViewBag.idNumberSortParm = "idNumber";
```

or make an enum with different sort parameters or implement sort strategy pattern or something else.